# Rails Exception: Action Controller sort_by nil:NilClass when attempting to error handle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a bit new to Ruby on Rails (and already loving it) and attempting to make a very simple webapp that lists posts with the submit form and the 'feed' on one page. I got a lot of these programming concepts from Michael Hartl's wonderful Rails Tutorial.

Posting works fine; the error is thrown when the form is submitted with no form data (to test error handling).

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm really trying to learn and your help is greatly appreciated.

I've searched over and over again for these exceptions and I can't seem to trace it. I think that the problem lies on the `@posts = Post.all` line, and I think that it's pulling the null post that wasn't saved, but that's the only conclusion I can come to, and the way to fix it isn't apparent to me.

If you need any more code, I'm happy to post it, and thanks so much for your help!

Here is the offending code that throws the error:

**/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to '/', :flash => { :success => "Awesomesauce! Your post has been broadcast (like a boss)!" }
    else
      @post.destroy
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.destroy
  end

end
```

**/app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :location, :text

  validates :author, presence: true
  validates :text, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140}


end
```

**index.html.erb** (I truncated some irrelevant code here)

```
<div class="span8 center">
        <%= render partial: "shared/flash_messages", flash: flash %>
        <%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
        <h4>Latest posts <span class="label label-info">Updated LIVE</span></h4>
        <ol class="posts">
            <% @posts.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.each do |post|%>
            <li>
                <span class="content"> <%= post.text %> </span>
                <span class="content muted">Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.author %> in <%= post.location %>. </span>
            </li>
            <% end %>
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
match '/', to: 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
```

The error that is thrown is as follows:

```
undefined method `sort_by' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:         <%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
12:         <h4>Latest posts <span class="label label-info">Updated LIVE</span></h4>
13:         <ol class="posts">
14:             <% @posts.sort_by{|t| - t.created_at.to_i}.each do |post|%>
15:             <li>
16:                 <span class="content"> <%= post.text %> </span>
17:                 <span class="content muted">Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.author %> in <%= post.location %>. </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `create` conditional, you should specify the action you want to render:

```
render :action => :index
```

This will prompt ActionController to completely re-render the `index` action while persisting certain elements – including validation error messages – in memory so that they're available to the view.

Your current code is failing because `render 'index'` renders out the `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` *template*, **not** the `index` *action*. Because you haven't instantiated the `@posts` instance variable in the `create` action, it isn't available to the template, hence you get the `nil:NilClass` error when you try to iterate through `@posts`.

Rendering the `index` action, rather than the template, resolves all this.

Comment: I attempted to substitute my code for yours and it's still throwing the same error on line 14. I also tried, substituting `redirect_to '/'` with `render :action => :index` and even a valid post throws the same error. Any other ideas about how to solve this? Also should note that I'm running Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3-HEAD (cron updates it nightly from homebrew).

Comment: Try adding `@posts = Post.all` to your `create` action, right below `@post = Post.new(params[:post])`.

Comment: That's perfect, and the exceptions have ceased. Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `render 'index'` does not run the code inside the `#index` action. It only renders the template. So `@posts` is undefined when your Post creation fails and the index is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider replacing `redirect_to '/'` and `render 'index'` with `redirect_to root_path` or `redirect_to posts_path`. That way you can manage your routes in their home, config/routes.rb and they aren't hardcoded in.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out; I forgot that was proper practice. I've fixed `routes.rb` and it's much better now. Thanks for helping with that.